# Cannot iterate over unique elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array of errors as below:

```
n.errors.full_messages
# => ["Password can't be blank", "Password can't be blank", "Password is too short (minimum is 3 characters)"]
```

I would like to iterate over the unique elements of this array and display them on the screen.

Validation model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  before_save { self.username = username.downcase }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
end

n.errors.full_messages.uniq do |a|
  puts a
end
```

`uniq` is not working, and `"Password can't be blank"` appears twice in my array. Any ideas?

```
Password can't be blank
Password can't be blank
Password is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
# => ["Password can't be blank"]
```

Comment: try `n.errors.full_messages.uniq.each do |a|`

Comment: @BroiSatse It worked! Post it as an answer so that I can accept, and if possible, with an explanation why only `.uniq` is not enough ?

Comment: Isn't it better to just stop the duplicate error message in the first place? Can you post the validation on whatever model `n` is?

Comment: Is there a password confirmation field that generates the second message?

Comment: @Stefan No, it its a (really) basic signup page with two text inputs: username and password.

Comment: no need for `presence: true` this is what is causing the duplicate `has_secure_password` adds validations for "*The following validations are added automatically:

    Password must be present on creation

    Password length should be less than or equal to 72 characters

    Confirmation of password (using a password_confirmation attribute)*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: This doesn't actually answer the question, use the answer from @BroiSatse if google brought you here.

The reason you are getting that message twice is because of `has_secure_password`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password

The first bullet point appears to add validation that makes the password required.

In your model you also add

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
```

The `presence: true` part of this adds the same validation. Remove this so its:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 3 }
```

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`uniqe` with a block uses value of the block to compare the elements. What you want is:

```
n.errors.full_messages.uniq.each do |m|
```

Anyhow, I think you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle - your problem is not how to avoid displaying duplicate messages, but how this duplication happened.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a string comparison.

Have the array that is problematic to you. Go over it and save the elements one by one to a new array.

Now when the first one is added to the new array, check that the elements allready in the array don't match the new element to be added. E.g: `"My string".eql? "My sting"`

There might be of course a more clever way to do this in Ruby. But that would be the idea when doing it in other languages manually.